# Google Chrome Omnibox API -- automatically select first option on enter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

So I'm trying to build a simple Omnibox extension for Chrome for personal use. It works like any other Omnibox extension: you enter the extension keyword and press tab, which gives the extension control of the omnibox. Then you type in a phrase or whatnot and a list of suggestions pop up below the omnibox. Then you can use the arrow keys or mouse to select a suggestion and then the browser navigates to the page associated with that suggestion. All of that works perfectly fine.

However, what I'd like it to do is that when I press enter in without having selected a suggestion, I'd like the browser to go to the first suggestion from the suggestion list. Instead what happens right now, I get this error page:

[image: chrome error page]

I couldn't find any answers in the documentation on this. This is what my code looks like right now (in `background.js`):

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(
    function(text, suggest)
    {
        text = text.replace(" ", "");
        suggest([
            { content: "http://reddit.com/r/" + text, description: "reddit.com/r/" + text },
            { content: "http://imgur.com/r/" + text, description: "imgur.com/r/" + text }
        ]);
    }
);

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(
    function(text)
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
        {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: text});
        });
    }
);

chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({ description: "visit /r/%s" });
```

So is there a way of setting the default action when the enter is pressed without a suggestion being selected? Sort of like the custom search functionality works by default in the Chrome omnibox?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within `chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener()`, you'll want to call `chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion()`.

So when you type something in the Omnibox, you'll want to make the first suggestion become the default suggestion (so you don't have to press the Down Arrow), and then `suggest()` any remaining suggestions like normal.

---

Example:

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(
    function(text, suggest)
    {
        text = text.replace(" ", "");

        // Add suggestions to an array
        var suggestions = [];
        suggestions.push({ content: "http://reddit.com/r/" + text, description: "reddit.com/r/" + text });
        suggestions.push({ content: "http://imgur.com/r/" + text, description: "imgur.com/r/" + text });

        // Set first suggestion as the default suggestion
        chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({description:suggestions[0].description});

        // Remove the first suggestion from the array since we just suggested it
        suggestions.shift();

        // Suggest the remaining suggestions
        suggest(suggestions);
    }
);

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(
    function(text)
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
        {
            var url;
            if (text.substr(0, 7) == 'http://') {
                url = text;

            // If text does not look like a URL, user probably selected the default suggestion, eg reddit.com for your example
            } else {
                url = 'http://reddit.com/r/' + text;
            }
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url});
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but I can't seem to be able to set a url in the object passed to setDefaultSuggestion(), only a description. Mind showing me an example if possible?

Comment: Added an example for you! `setDefaultSuggestion` is just for show, since it doesn't pass in anything meaningful. So if the user's `text` doesn't look like a URL, you can assume that they chose the default suggestion, eg reddit.com (in your code anyway).